# Problem with included modules when compiling program with mpifort

Tags: python, fortran, mpi

I'm working on a python tool for post-processing data written in a fortran simulation tool. As many of the methods are already implemented in fortran and I don't want to do resource-heavy calculations in python, I did following:

1. Wrote a fortran wrapper, initializing some data and importing modules from the simulation program.
2. Compiled the fortran modules with mpifort and linked them together in a shared library (.so)
3. Linked the shared library with the wrapper and created a new shared library I can load in python.

The first problem comes up when compiling the program modules. The compilation exits with an error, because it can't find a module file (which was compiled and in the module directory).

```
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -c src//decomp_2d.f90 -o obj//decomp_2d.o
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -c src//glassman.f90 -o obj//glassman.o
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -c src//ftt_generic.f90 -o obj//ftt_generic.o
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -c src//module_param.f90 -o obj//module_param.o
src//module_param.f90(3): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file$
  check INCLUDE paths.   [DECOMP_2D]
  use decomp_2d, only : mytype 
-----------^
```

To note here is, that both glassman.f90 and ftt_generic also use decomp_2d and seem to have no issue finding it.
Now if I run make again, everything compiles and my shared library is created:

```
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ ./obj//decomp_2d.o ./obj//glassman.o ./obj/ /fft_generic.o ./obj//module_param.o ./obj//io.o ./obj//variables.o ./obj//poisson.o ./obj//schemes.o ./obj//BC-Channel-flow.o ./obj//derive.o ./obj//parameters.o ./obj//tools.o -DVISU -DVISUEXTRA -DDOUBLE_PREC -DSTRETCHING -DPOST  -o lib/i3dlib.so
```

To create the other shared library:

```
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -Ilib/i3dlib.so ./obj//ipp.o -o lib/ipplib.so
```

In python I run:

```
from ctypes import cdll
ipp = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib/ipplib.so')
ipp.ipp_mp_init_()
```

What I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test/derivtest.py", line 5, in <module>
Ipp = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib/ipplib.so')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./lib/ipplib.so: undefined symbol: decomp_2d_mp_decomp_2d_init_
```

Here are the symbols from my compiled wrapper shared object

```
>> nm ./lib/ipplib.so

00000000002013b8 B __bss_start
00000000002013c0 b completed.7594
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000 N .debug_info_seg
                 U decomp_2d_mp_decomp_2d_init_
0000000000000c20 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000cb0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000201088 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
00000000002013b0 d __dso_handle
0000000000201098 d _DYNAMIC
00000000002013b8 D _edata
00000000002014e8 B _end
0000000000000e80 T _fini
                 U for_read_seq_lis
                 U for_write_seq_lis
0000000000000cf0 t frame_dummy
0000000000201080 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000001078 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000201398 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000f70 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000000be0 T _init
0000000000000d20 T ipp._
0000000000000d50 T ipp_mp_getfield_
0000000000000d60 T ipp_mp_init_
0000000000000d30 T ipp_mp_main_
0000000000000d40 T ipp_mp_setfield_
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000201090 d __JCR_END__
0000000000201090 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000002014a0 B mpi_fortran_argv_null_
00000000002014e0 B mpi_fortran_argvs_null_
0000000000201420 B mpi_fortran_bottom_
0000000000201460 B mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore_
0000000000201440 B mpi_fortran_in_place_
00000000002013e0 B mpi_fortran_statuses_ignore_
0000000000201400 B mpi_fortran_status_ignore_
0000000000201480 B mpi_fortran_unweighted_
00000000002014c0 B mpi_fortran_weights_empty_
                 U mpi_init_
                 U parameter_
0000000000000c60 t register_tm_clones
                 U schemes_
0000000000000e8c r __STRLITPACK_0
0000000000000e98 r __STRLITPACK_2.0.3
0000000000000ea0 r __STRLITPACK_3.0.3
00000000002013b8 d __TMC_END__
                 U var_mp_init_variables_
```

And i3dlib.so has the line

```
0000000000049fc0 T decomp_2d_mp_decomp_2d_init_
```

Comment: You should have `ipplib.so` depend on `id3lib.so`

Answer (score 1):

Problem (partially) solved. I had a typo in the compiler command:

```
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -Ilib/i3dlib.so ./obj//ipp.o -o lib/ipplib.so
```

Instead of:

```
mpifort -fPIC -xHost -fpp -O3 -heap-arrays -shared -mcmodel=large -safe-cray-ptr -g -traceback -I./obj/ -module ./obj/ -I./obj/ lib/i3dlib.so ./obj//ipp.o -o lib/ipplib.so
```

Before the libraries were not linked. Now I can call the method I wanted from python.

The other problem persists though - why do I have to compile twice? Why can't it see the compiled module in the include-directory on the first run but it can see it on the second?

Comment: do you compile your files in sequence via a script ? or do you build your app in parallel (e.g. `make -j`) ? in the latter case, some dependencies might be missing.